# gpu.js in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, webcl, gpu.js

I'm trying to run gpu.js in a web worker, but can't seem to get it to work at all.

I'm running importScripts to load the library within the worker, but I'm not getting the GPU object in the worker context.

Comment: Looks like `gpu.js` devs are working on Web Worker support: https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/issues/140#issuecomment-315576228 & https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/issues/5

Comment: Thanks, i hadn't spotted that issue.